# Large + Offset Function in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get top three large data from another sheet by using offset along with match but after running the below code, I am getting #VALUE error in the cell. I don't know why there is an error and how to resolve it.

```
Sub Dashboard()

Dim i As Integer, a As Integer, j As Integer, sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
a = sh.Range("B3", sh.Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
For i = 3 To a
    For j = 1 To 3
        If i < (a + 1) Then
            ref = Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A2")
            ro = Application.Match(Cells(i, 2), Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A3:A15000"), 0)
            Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
            co = Application.Match(Cells(2, 4),Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A1:P1"), 0) - 1
            hei = Application.Match(Cells(i, 2), Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A3:A15000"), 0)
            wid = 1
            Cells(i, 4) = Application.Large("Offset(ref, ro, co, hei, wid)", j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `Cells(i, 4) = Application.Large(ref.Offset(ro, co).Resize(hei, wid), j)`

Comment: its giving me an error Run-time error '424' Object required

Comment: you need to to use `Set ref = Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A2")`

Comment: its done but instead of getting top three numbers, i got 2nd or third number and all are same in top three data cells

Comment: for example Real Estate 8.5 which is repeating in the other two cells as well. I noticed something that when I run the code, it shows first largest number but after completion it shows 2nd largest and populating the same in the remaining cell

Comment: That is because your writing to same cell for all iteration of j. Also your example of Real Estate is unclear because we can't see your Excel data file. You will have to decide where the top 3 value are going to be written into which column

Comment: my data is the price of stocks, in sheet Re_PE_Comdy_FX_IR Column A (Name of the Company) and the other column contains different period price change. I am trying to find the top 3 change in price with respect to the selection of period. please advice how can I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use different columns to write the results.

```
For i = 3 To a
For j = 1 To 3
    If i < (a + 1) Then
        Set ref = Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A2")
        ro = Application.Match(Cells(i, 2), Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A3:A15000"), 0)
        Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
        co = Application.Match(Cells(2, 4),Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A1:P1"), 0) - 1
        hei = Application.Match(Cells(i, 2), Sheets("RE_PE_Comdy_FX_IR").Range("A3:A15000"), 0)
        wid = 1
        'Write to different columns maybe??
        Cells(i, 4 + j - 1) = Application.Large(ref.Offset(ro, co).Resize(hei, wid), j)
    End If
Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate!